# ReactJs Unable to access dictionary in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am unable to access a dictionary in this.state.

My component constructor actually looks like below

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    hexDoneData:{},
    donutData : {}, 
  } 
}
```

In some method I am actually updating this.state.hexDoneData dictionary. Updating is happening fine. But I am unable to read this dictionary. Below is the function where I am trying to read dictionary.

```
     loadHexagonChart(){
console.log("this.state.hexDoneData : ",this.state.hexDoneData)
    console.log("this.state.hexDoneData.linux : ",this.state.hexDoneData.linux)
      }
```

Console output for the console statement looks like below
[image]

this.state.hexDoneData.linux is undefined while this.state.hexDoneData looks like dictionary which has key linux. I tried  this.state.hexDoneData['linux'] it didn't work. Even map function is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to initialize linux and windows under hexDoneData in constructor, hexDoneData: {
linux: 0,
windows:0,
}

Comment: Can't I dynamically add key:value pair to state? Like we do in regular javascript dictionaries?

Comment: Inside "this.state.hexDoneData" state variable values is updating after when you print into console. Please try to print in console on click of some function.

Comment: can you show the updating code as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state={
  hexDoneData:{
   linux: '',
  },
  donutData : {}, 
 } 
}
```

Also call this function in any event where you want to desired output, 
 because it's state is updating.

```
loadHexagonChart(){
  console.log(this.state.hexDoneData.linux);
}
```